# unable to use different ruby version or even set as default

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have tried to use different ruby version, but it keeps failing - when i check with ruby -v, it's still the default system. There's no luck too when I try to use as default too. When I typed to set as default, it's taking forever to respond. Am I doing it right?

I have re-install ruby anyway. Here's the log:

```
comnom@comnom-G41T-R3:~/hacks/SiriProxy$ rvm use 1.9.3
Using /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0
comnom@comnom-G41T-R3:~/hacks/SiriProxy$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux]
comnom@comnom-G41T-R3:~/hacks/SiriProxy$
```

Comment: Just curious, what do you see if you type "which ruby"

Comment: Append the output of `rvm info` to your question. Also, confirm that you followed the "Troubleshooting Your Install" information on the RVM [installation page](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install).

Comment: it respond me "/usr/bin/ruby"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting up the .bash_profile as instructed afte the RVM installation [http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/). In the case of multi user installations you want to make sure your OS respects and loads scripts in /etc/profile. If you have followed all of these steps, ensure you have logged out and logged back in since the install.